# How does `vue2-flip-countdown` modify the text below the countdown to support vue-i18n

Tags: vuejs2

I want to modify Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds below the countdown to support vue-i18n. how to modify

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <flip-countdown deadline="2025-04-02 09:34:33"></flip-countdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like it, But there is a problem that cannot be updated with language switching.

```js
<flip-countdown deadline="2025-04-02 09:34:33" :label="{ days: `${this.$t('user.days')}`, hours: `${this.$t('pool.hours')}`, minutes: `${this.$t('messages.minute')}`, seconds: `${this.$t('pool.seconds')}` }"></flip-countdown>
```